# How do I get Maven to use the correct repositories?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, build

I have just checked out some projects and need to build them, however I installed Maven quite some time ago (6 months maybe?) and really haven't used it since - the `pom.xml` for the project I have doesn't have this "http://repo1.maven.org/myurlhere" anywhere in it - it has the absolute `url` where the Maven repo is for the project, but Maven is still trying to download from the general Maven repo:

```
Macintosh:trunk$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/url/project/project/x.x/project-x.x.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'url.project:project:pom:x.x' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

GroupId: url.project
ArtifactId: project
Version: x.x

Reason: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  url.project:project:pom:x.x

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/)
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm not doing right?
Basically, I have just checked the projects out from the command line, `cd`-ed into the directory and ran `mvn clean install` - nothing else.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 87):

> the pom.xml for the project I have doesn't have this "http://repo1.maven.org/myurlhere" anywhere in it

**All** projects have http://repo1.maven.org/ declared as `<repository>` (and `<pluginRepository>`) by default. This repository, which is called the *central* repository, is inherited like others default settings from the "Super POM" (all projects inherit from the Super POM). So a POM is actually a combination of the Super POM, any parent POMs and the current POM. This combination is called the "effective POM" and can be printed using the `effective-pom` goal of the Maven Help plugin (useful for debugging).

And indeed, if you run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

You'll see at least the following:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

> it has the absolute url where the maven repo is for the project but maven is still trying to download from the general maven repo

Maven will try to find dependencies in all repositories declared, including in the *central* one which is there by default as we saw. But, according to the trace you are showing, you only have **one** repository defined (the central repository) or maven would print something like this:

```
Reason: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  url.project:project:pom:x.x

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/),
  another-repository (http://another/repository)
```

So, basically, maven is unable to find the `url.project:project:pom:x.x` because it is not available in central.

But without knowing which project you've checked out (it has maybe specific instructions) or which dependency is missing (it can maybe be found in another repository), it's impossible to help you further.

Comment: to see exactly where it checks as it runs, run `mvn -U dependency:resolve`  - `-U` forces mvn to retry, otherwise it caches the failure as metadata

Comment: Thank you! This answer has just helped me! `pluginRepository` was the key (in addition to `repository`), because the plugin from «that» (third-party) repository is referenced.

Comment: Note the URLs have changed to 'https' [MavenCentral](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

Answer (score 36):

By default, Maven will always look in the official Maven repository, which is http://repo1.maven.org.

When Maven tries to build a project, it will look in your local repository (by default `~/.m2/repository` but you can configure it by changing the `<localRepository>` value in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`) to find any dependency, plugin or report defined in your `pom.xml`. If the adequate artifact is not found in your local repository, it will look in all external repositories configured, starting with the default one, http://repo1.maven.org.

You can configure Maven to avoid this default repository by setting a mirror in your `settings.xml` file:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>repoMirror</id>
        <name>Our mirror for Maven repository</name>
        <url>http://the/server/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This way, instead of contacting `http://repo1.maven.org`, Maven will contact your entreprise repository (`http://the/server` in this example).

If you want to add another repository, you can define a new one in your settings.xml file:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>foo.bar</id>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <url>http://new/repository/server</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
```

You can see the complete `settings.xml` model [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Concerning the `clean` process, you can ask Maven to run it *offline*. In this case, Maven will not try to reach any external repositories:

```
mvn -o clean
```

Comment: Maven doesn't resolve dependencies during clean, no need to run it offline (at least not with maven 2.2.1 and the clean plugin 2.2).

Comment: NEVER use the wildcard "*" expression when defining mirrors or you will not be able to build third party vendor tools or sample projects that define custom repositories within their poms.

Comment: Whats the equivalent to defining and overriding this in my project pom.xml file?

Comment: Why <mirror> overwrites the central repository?

Comment: This is great info. But is the central maven repository http://repo1.maven.org as you state above or http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, as shown at http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories?

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**

All maven POMs inherit from a base [**Super POM**](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM).
The snippet below is part of the Super POM for Maven 3.5.4.

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you have missed here is this:

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers

> The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the repositories and distributionManagement elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml.

This is the prefered way of using custom repos. So probably what is happening is that the url of this repo is in settings.xml of the build server.

Once you get hold of the url and credentials, you can put them in your machine here: `~/.m2/settings.xml` like this:

```
<settings ...> 

        .
        .
        .
        <servers>
            <server>
              <id>internal-repository-group</id>
              <username>YOUR-USERNAME-HERE</username>
              <password>YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE</password>
            </server>
        </servers>
</settings>
```

**EDIT:**

You then need to refer this repository into project POM. The id *internal-repository-group* can be used in every project. You can setup multiple repos and credentials setting using different IDs in settings xml.

The advantage of this approach is that project can be shared without worrying about the credentials and don't have to mention the credentials in every project.

Following is a sample pom of a project using "internal-repository-group"

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>internal-repository-group</id>
        <name>repo-name</name>
        <url>http://project.com/yourrepourl/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, all Maven is telling you is that certain dependencies in your project are not available in the central maven repository. The default is to look in your local .m2 folder (local repository), and then any configured repositories in your POM, and then the central maven repository. Look at the repositories [section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) of the Maven reference.

The problem is that the project that was checked in didn't configure the POM in such a way that all the dependencies could be found and the project could be built from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

change the settings.xml from your maven folder e.g
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\conf
check above path..